# SonataAdminBundle sonata_type_model just displays text of id, not choice menu

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, sonata-admin

I have a many-to-one relationship between Property and PropertyType (A Property can belong to only one property type). I have been trying to implement SonataAdminBundle's 'sonata_type_model' into my create/edit form.

```
class PropertyAdmin extends Admin
{
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
        ->add('propertyType', 'sonata_type_model', array('property' => 'name'));

    }
}
```

However, a select menu is not displayed. Instead, there is just text corresponding to the id of property type. If it helps, I am using Doctrine2.

How can I display a select menu of property types?

Answer (score 1):

This might mean that you haven't created an Admin class for the other object in you relation ('propertyType' in your case).

If that is so, then you simply need to create a PropertyTypeAdmin class (in the same way as your created your PropertyAdmin class) to see the dropdown field, which will be automatically generated by Sonata Admin.